# Editing Options on Sharepoint

Tags: promoted-links, app-part, editing-menu

I am currently trying to build a team page off of my company SharePoint in Office 365. I have created the page, added apps as well as articles to the site asset library and in the Site Content. I am trying to get my "Promoted Links" App Part to post to the Home Page, However I am not able to.

I have looked on similar posts of people being to add them when clicking "Edit" a ribbon opens up for them to fully customize the field. I am not sure how to get access to this ribbon? Or if its because of Permissions that have been set by site admins.

Comment: You are in a classic Team Site or publishing site, right? And you have added some  items in the promoted links list?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just am unable to add them from my Site Content list to my home page.